# VueJs importing and using components with two different name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, frontend

I have a component called Sidebar in `SideBar.vue` file and have imported in `index.vue` as below, It is working.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <side-bar @close="isOpen = false" />
  </div>
</template>

import SideBar from '@/common/SideBar';
export default {
  components: {
    SideBar,
  },
}
```

If I declared in the components like below, it is also working.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <some-thing @close="isOpen = false" />
  </div>
</template>

import SideBar from '@/common/SideBar';
export default {
  components: {
    'some-thing': SideBar,
  },
}
```

My question is how does vue map `side-bar` with `SideBar` automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue automatically by default maps `CamelCase` components with `kebab-case` names.
So your component name `SideBar` which is in camelCase automatically gets mapped with name `side-bar` which is in kebab-case.
In the html template it is advised to use kebab case instead of camelCase and in Javascript it is advised to use camelCase instead of kebab-case.
They are just styling conventions. You can use either of the styles in your html template or in javascript code. It will work.

I suggest you read more about it from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing)